# In Android Kotlin App Dev, Firebase says The email address is badly formatted

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Here's my Kotlin activity code:

```
package com.florize.nostagram

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var auth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        email_login_button.setOnClickListener {
            signinAndSignup()
        }
    }

    fun signinAndSignup() {
        auth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email_edittext.toString().trim(),
            password_edittext.toString()
        )
            ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    //Creating a user account
                    moveMainPage(task.result?.user)
                } else if (task.exception?.message.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    //Show the error message
                    Toast.makeText(this, task.exception?.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    //Login if you have account
                    signinEmail()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and my layout code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_edittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="@string/email" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I set the inputType for Email Field.
but Firebase Toast says "The email address is badly formatted.".
and I added trim() behind the "email_edittext.toString()"
doesn't work. still same error.
How can I fix it?

(I cut my Kotlin activity code because it's too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
auth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email_edittext.toString().trim(),
            password_edittext.toString()
        )
```

into this:

```
auth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email_edittext.text.toString().trim(),
            password_edittext.text.toString()
        )
```

You need to use the `text` property to access the value of the `textfield`